# Unable to connect L2TP/IPSec VPN from ubuntu 18.04 to my Unifi Gateway Pro 4

Tags: network-manager, vpn

I've recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my macbook mid 2013. I've setup my VPN on Ubuntu, using L2TP/IPsec and am unable to connect to my USG. I read that there are issues with kernel 4.15.x, and that L2TP doesn't really work, can anyone point me in the right direction to get this working??

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic) and 16.04 (xenial) are affected by this [xl2tpd kernel 4.15.x issue](https://github.com/xelerance/xl2tpd/issues/147) as xenial now has the same kernel version as bionic in its updates repository.

xl2tpd packages with backported patch to workaround this kernel issue are now in their respective updates repositories:

- 18.04 (bionic) - [xl2tpd 1.3.10-1ubuntu1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xl2tpd/1.3.10-1ubuntu1)
- 16.04 (xenial) - [xl2tpd 1.3.6+dfsg-4ubuntu0.16.04.2](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xl2tpd/1.3.6+dfsg-4ubuntu0.16.04.2)

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.1: After updating and upgrading via apt the version 1.3.10-1ubuntu 
of xl2tpd were installed. In order for it to work properly, I had to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure network-manager-pptp-gnome` additionally. 
@config: Phase 1 `3des-sha1-modp1024` and Phase 2 `3des-sha1` Algorithms were required.